# ROC/AUC curves for matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, roc, auc

I have a lot of data that comes from some experiment, just one column "measure" and would like to calculate [ROC/AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curves. I use matplotlib and had a look, but found no way to do with  it. I wonder if anyone can share experiences with matplotlib or with any other open source easy to use library for ROC/AUC curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib is mostly used for plotting things, so you'd need to calculate the curves first and then plot them with matplotlib.  There seem to be multiple relevant Python modules:
[scipy roc_curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve)
[PyROC](http://code.google.com/p/pyplotmining/wiki/HowToUseIt)
[CROC](http://swami.wustl.edu/CROC/)
[yard](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yard)

Comment: Now, sklearn has this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html

Comment: @hlin117: thanks.  I added it (though a slightly different link)